# Jackson deserialization failed on JsonCreator

Tags: json, serialization, jackson

```
public class TestObj {
    public final String name;
    public final int age;

    @JsonCreator
    public TestObj(@JsonProperty("name") String name, @JsonProperty("age") int age)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }
}
```

Above class was serialized into {"name":"tt","age":1}

When i tried to deserialize it:

```
f = m.readValue(json, TestObj.class);
```

I got exception:

```
org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: No suitable constructor found for type [simple type, class TestObj]: can not instantiate from JSON object (need to add/enable type information?)
```

Any clue?

Comment: try to add an empty constructor

Comment: The exception mentions the UdafMapperFunction class, not TestObj

Comment: Sorry. Suppose to hide class name :)

Answer (score 1):

Well..That's a very stupid issue. I used JsonProperty from another version of Jackson which has different package path. So the deserializer cannot figure out all the annotation I wrote.

Comment: Saw your answer while I was writing this comment about the version

Comment: Alas, this is relatively common problem. Would have suggested it as a likely cause, glad you figured it out.